# How I could be able to compare undefined in JS?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm very new to JS.

Lets say I have an object named `test` which doesn't have a property `missing`. But I try to access the same:

```
test.missing //getting undefined as output
```

Now I'm trying to access the `missing` properties ( like this `test.missing.404` ) which will give me a `TypeError`. But my book says we can get rid of this `TypeError` by like this:

```
test.missing && test.missing.404
```

Now my big question is how one can do a `&&` against the `undefined` type and `TypeError` type. Couldn't able to guess what Js is doing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined` in js is treated as `false` and if something has value it is treated as `true`, so:

```
//if test.missing is NOT undefined and test.missing.404 is also NOT undefined
if (test.missing && test.missing.404)
```

Comment: `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, and `""` are falsy, everything else it truthy.  I only mention this because some might consider `""` to "have value", and/or `[]` to not have value... Easier to be explicit about falsy values, there are only the 6 :)

Comment: @gnarf quirk: `document.all` also evaluates to `false` due to historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

First of you should know that JS like many other programming languages uses short circuit technique during comparison. So in this case if the first condition is false then there is no need to check the next condition(s). This is due to the fact that `0 && X`  will always result 0 .

With that said, `test.missing && test.missing.404` can be perceive as "if the test object has missing property and the (test object's) missing property has 404 property" then proceed. Which the JS intepreter will completely ignore the check for 404 property on missing property if the test object has no missing property in the first place.

So the point is the above code is not && comparison of undefined and TypeError but rather check for missing property first and 404 property if first property exists. I hope this makes sense ad explains it well enough.